# Using " as a character in a statement

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I am trying to use " as a character in my code, but VBA always auto corrects it as excess characters (like if I try `"""`). I tried to use the `Char(34)` character code but it still doesn't work. I want to loop through cells and search for values within the cell such as "`ActiveCell.Value`" but the code doesn't recognize " as a character. Here is the code:

```
Sub zero()

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & Chr(34) & ActiveCell.Value & Chr(34))

ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to double up the quotes to escape them in VBA, so `doubleQuotes = """"` is assigning one double-quote character, which is indeed `Chr(34)`. "but it doesn't work" isn't a useful problem description we can work with. How is it failing?

Comment: Could you tell us what `Debug.Print "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & Chr(34) & ActiveCell.Value & Chr(34) ` returns?

Comment: This code works 100% fine for me. Are you getting an error, incorrect results? What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **four** rabbits ears within a VBA string for a single quotation character.

For this reason I define

```
Public Const vbQuote As String = """"
```

and use in this way

```
"https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & vbQuote & ActiveCell.Value & vbQuote
```

Comment: Thank you this method worked, I was actually asked by a colleague who doesn't have a SO account to post this that's why I couldn't define clearly what the problem was.